# Sum all rows where first column matches a pattern

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I exported some data from Google Analytics I want to group into smaller bit sized chunks. Here is the metrics I exported. In the parenthesis, those are the calculations I want to perform on each metric column when pages are grouped together.

```
Users (sum), Avg. Session Duration (avg), Bounce Rate (avg), Pageviews (sum), Goal Completions (sum), Page Value (avg)
```

The dimension I segment all this data on is `Landing Page`. Within this big data dump, there are 15 different sub-domains. I want to split landing pages for each sub-domain in two, like so:

```
www.example.com                      <RAW DATA FOR HOME PAGE>
www.example.com/everything-else      <AVG & SUM DATA OF METRICS ABOVE>
sub1.example.com                     <RAW DATA FOR HOME PAGE>
sub1.example.com/everything-else     <AVG & SUM DATA OF METRICS ABOVE>
sub2.example.com                     <RAW DATA FOR HOME PAGE>
sub2.example.com/everything-else     <AVG & SUM DATA OF METRICS ABOVE>
```

So basically if the row about a sub-domain homepage, we leave the data as is in the new table. If it's an interior page, I want that data grouped together to sum/avg each column.

I figured I needed to use something like VLOOKUP, to check (1) if the first part of the string matches and (2) to see if anything comes after .com/.

Having difficulty with this though.

Comment: What about 'sumif' or 'averageif'? Or pivot table?

Comment: I am open to anything, I am just lost. This is more advanced than I am at Excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a little unclear on how you get the sub-domain to correspond to the data (is it in one table, multiples?), also I'm not sure what you mean by RAW data.  However, your solution could look like this:

Since you want to key off the right side to provide different output you should try something like the following:

```
=if(right(a2,4)=".com",[get raw data], [get avg data])
```

This will allow you to switch between the two.  How you "[get raw data]", or "[get avg data]" is determined by how your data is imported.  Personally, I would put the above "if" statment in each column, corresponding to the columns of data, and where you don't want the data to show for the RAW data (again not sure what this is) I would make the "[get raw data]" = "".  This will blank it out.  You could use a vlookup in the get raw data that uses the COLUMN() (add one of course for site name column offset) function to identify which column you are in and pull this from the vlookup table.

Again more clarity and I can give you a better answer, but I think you are looking at something like this:

```
=IF(RIGHT(A1,4)=".com",VLOOKUP(A1,WHEREEVER!A:B,column()+1,FALSE),VLOOKUP(A1,everythingelse!A:G,COLUMN()+1,FALSE))
```

**EDIT**  I was thinking about this some more.  For your calculations, for each column you might want to replace the vlookup, above, with a sumif(), it will look something like this:

```
=IF(RIGHT(A1,4)=".com",[get RAW data],sumif(sourcedatatable!a:a,=a1,sourcedatatable!b:b))
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I have been traveling. This will work nicely. I appreciate it!